# How to load YAML file from Github?

Tags: python, github, yaml

I have a (private) Github repository where I have a YAML file. With my Python script I would like this file to be automatically loaded and parsed.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: "*What is the best way to do that?*" The "*best*" way to do anything is most often highly subjective depending on what factors you value in making such a determination; questions of which type are explicitly disallowed per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic]. Edit your question to be answerable with facts and citable sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your Git access token: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token
2. Request the raw file with headers `Authorization: token ACCESS_TOKEN` and `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw`

Answer (score 0):

Using the requests module, you can get direct http access to a file from github `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[user]/[repo]/[branch]/[filename].yaml`

```py
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.content)
```

Edit: formatting errors